# Установка значений переменных из C# в flash

Tags: c#, flash, actionscript, activex

Есть готовый флеш ролик с AS2 или AS1(точно не знаю), размещенный на форме в C#, нужно задавать значения его глобальных переменных из C#, ну или Java (как из нее не знаю, но если возможно - тоже сойдет).
Для этого в C# есть функция AxShockwaveFlash.SetVariable(string name, string value). Она работает, но только с локальными переменными, с глобальными реакции никакой, т.е.:

```
axShockwaveFlash.SetVariable("gVar.var", "3");
axShockwaveFlash.SetVariable("_global.gVar.var", "3");
```

и подобные вариации эффекта не дают (хотя тоже самое запросто работает в java script),

```
axShockwaveFlash.SetVariable("localVar", "3");
```

а вот так, с локальными переменными, работает замечательно

Кто знает, подскажите в чем дело? Инет перерыл, но ответа не нашел. Или может есть другие варианты как можно передать значения не переписывая сам флеш-ролик?

Answer (score 2):

Насчет глобальных переменных, точно сказать не могу, но можно обращаться к свойствам элементов swf формы через _root.
Также когда организовывал пользовательское взаимодействие Flash и С# использовал код интерфейса в виде свойств, на уровне Flash ролика
AS2

```
var getSomething =   function ():Number {
    return Graph.Something;
}
var setSomething = function(value) {
    Graph.Something= Number(value);
}
_root.addProperty("FSomething", getSomething , setSomething );
```

C#

```
axShockwaveFlash.SetVariable("FSomething", "3");
axShockwaveFlash.GetVariable("FSomething");
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ:)
Увы, но я не смогу так сделать, т.к. не имею исходных кодов Flash ролика

Comment: можно попробовать получить доступ к свойствам всех объектов на ролике от MovieClip до TextField, через _root. Например с помощью свойства text объекта TextField  можно  изменить значение текстового поля во Flash на свое.

Comment: Тоже не получается через _root  :(